# Option characters in PHP regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to find a way to have optional characters in a PHP regex function (statement).  I'm trying to enter a very simple address consisting of numeric data, a space, a street name with a capital letter, a street, boulevard, avenue etc and then optional characters of NSWE only.   Here's what I have so far...

So far what works and what doesn't...

133 Times Road (doesn't work)

133 Times Road_ (the underscore is actually a space and this works)

133 Times Road A (works, but should not)

133 Times Road N

Suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
d+\s[A-z]+\s[A-z]+(\s+[NSWE])*?
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/tKuM77/1

Comment: That will match other characters besides 0-9 anyways, like Hindu-Arabic Numerals. Be more specific as to what you actually want the regex to do. Please rewrite the question.

Comment: Using `[A-z]` to match all letters is generally a bad idea, because the characters square brackets, backslash, carrot, underscore, and backtick are included in this range as well.

Comment: So would [A-Za-z] be better in this situation?

Comment: Yep, [A-Za-z] is typically how you'd do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
\d+ [A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+( [NSWE])?
```

I replaced the `\s` with spaces so new lines or tabs in between are not allowed. If you don't want it like that you can stay with

```
\d+\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+(\s[NSWE])?
```

I changed `[A-z]+` to `[A-Z][a-z]+` for two reasons: You're only allowed to use one capital letter and keys like underscores will not work now anymore.
If I misunderstood you and you wanted to add as many letters of [NSWE] as you'd like, you could use this:

```
\d+ [A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+( [NSWE]+)?
```

[image: Here you can see it in action]

Here you can see it in action.

If it works I was the one who told you how to do it, if it doesn't I don't know who invented this broken regex.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Works perfectly for what I need to do.

Comment: Yes it works.  Thank you for reminding me to do this.